# Trying to understand how dynamic_cast works

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

can anyone tell what are the exact checks that dynamic_cast does? how can there be a scenario where I can downcast to the grandson and fail to downcast to the son? (using normal inheritance and not diamond)

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is used to go from parent to child, not the other way around.  The other way around can just use a `static_cast`

Comment: This question is unlikely to help your other one or solve the problem you have with the other.

Comment: It is still because your program has undefined behaviour, just like it was an hour ago. Understanding `dynamic_cast` will not help you locate that problem.

Comment: better think of a better design when you don't have to `dynamic_cast` (or check for a particular type in any other ways)

Comment: C++ compilers support [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information#C++_%E2%80%93_dynamic_cast_and_Java_cast), which permits discovering the actual type of an object at runtime.  If it is enabled, if not then a dynamic_cast devolves to a static_cast.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Answer (score 1):

> what are the exact checks that dynamic_cast does?

It checks whether the dynamic type of the pointed object is actually the cast target type (or a type derived from it) or not.

> how can there be a scenario where I can downcast to the grandson and fail to downcast to the son?

Cast to a child class can be ambiguous, in which case the cast won't work.

Comment: "Ill-formed"? Isn't this one of the cases where `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer (when casting to a pointer type), or throws an exception (when casting to a reference type).

Comment: @PeteBecker Hmm, I remember seeing an error in such case. I suppose there can be various cases where it can or cannot be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the exact checks that dynamic_cast does?

consider the following line of code

```
dynamic_cast<t*>(a)
```

if `a` is of type `t*` or an accessible base class of `t`, the result is exactly as if we assigned `a` to `t*`.

dynamic_cast can be used to deal with the case in which the the correctness of the conversion cannot be determined by the compiler, In that case, dynamic_cast looks at the object pointed to by `a`. If that object is of class `t` or has a unique base class of type `t`, then dynamic_cast returns a pointer of type `t*` to that object else `0` is returned.

And If we want a down cast or cross cast a `dynamic_cast` would require a pointer or a reference to a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 0):

There are two situations where `dynamic_cast` does something that `static_cast` doesn't, which overlap in complex inheritance hierachies.

Firstly it has defined behaviour if you don't have an object of the target type.

```
class Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
class Derived : public Base {};

Base b;
Derived d;

Base * b1 = &d; // Points to Base subobject
Derived * d1 = static_cast<Derived *>(b1); // Ok, equal to &d

Base * b2 = &b;
// Derived * d2 = static_cast<Derived *>(b2); // Undefined behaviour
Derived * d3 = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(b2); // Ok, d3 is null
```

Secondly you can cast "unrelated" types if you have an object that inherits both.

```
class Left { virtual ~Left() = default; };
class Right { virtual ~Right() = default; };
class Mixed : public Left, public Right { };

Mixed m;
Left * l = &m; // Points to Left subobject of m
// Right * r1 = static_cast<Right *>(l); // compile error, unrelated types
Right * r2 = dynamic_cast<Right *>(l); // Ok, r points to Right subobject of m
```